# Why is my subscription in Report Manager changing the value/field parameter?

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2012, reportmanager

I have set up a report in Report Manager which has several subscriptions going to different email addresses, based on a value parameter 'service'.
The list of available values for this parameter is dynamically generated by a SQL stored procedure which selects all distinct services which exist in the database; this way if a service gets added, it will be picked up. The query is structured in such a way that the list order should be maintained.

However, I've been told recently that data in reports was incorrect and when I checked the subscription, the value for 'service' was not what I had previously set it to when the report was initially created.

How is the system altering this value?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the situation - you have a data driven subscription (ie, the value of service is pulled from the database), but you also "set" the value for service to something when you initially created the report? Do you mean you populated the table being used in the data driven subscription? Have you checked what's in the table? "The system" certainly won't be altering the value of data in a table all by itself.

Comment: Presumably the stored procedure is returning a key+value pair for each service, i.e.: a service ID and a service display name that gets shown in the parameter list. Do the old service IDs change when you add new services?